# Why does a VS 2010 project compilation, generates pdb files, when building in Release and Debug mode?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, compilation

I am building my window service c# project of VS 2010 in Release mode. My first chance to get surprised was that it's creating pdb files even  in release in mode. I was not able to load the debug symbols after attaching the process for debugging.

My question is that if we have pdb files in both  debug and release mode then why there is need for two compilation mode.

Comment: Quick question. What type of project? .NET, C++?

Comment: Check in project settings->Build->Advanced->Advanced Build Settings->Debug Info. I think if it is set to pdb-only in release mode, it will generate the pdb files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> My question is that if we have pdb files in both debug and release mode then why there is need for two compilation mode

There are differences *other* than PDB generation between debug and release. If you go into the Build properties and go into "Advanced", there are different levels of debug information to be generated - Full, PDB-only and None.

In addition, there are different levels of compile-time optimization, and the presence of different preprocessor symbols (e.g. so that each `Debug.Assert` will be present or absent).

Of course you can have your own varieties of build configuration too, with a variety of options.

Comment: what is difference between Full and PDB-only?

Comment: and http://mariangemarcano.blogspot.com/2011/11/visual-studio-debugging-and-remote.html

Answer (score 2):

There are many reasons why there is a debug/release mode, unrelated to the creation of PDB files.

VS executes your compiled programs faster in release mode.  In addition, there are compiler directives that can change the way the program behaves if you are in debug vs release mode.  For example, you can use compiler directives to disable your top-level `try` `catch` blocks so that you can isolate an exception that is being thrown to a specific line of code.

That's just a couple of examples.  In short, debug mode has many more purposes than just creating PDB files for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can have more than two compilation modes. Usually, debug and release mean stand for whether you want optimizations or not. Regardless, you can still generate debug information, only a PDB for a release build won't be of much help. Inline functions, variables can be excluded, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I recently did a winupdate(20120508) and Visual studio seemed to be really slow debugging afterwards
with a 1 minute delay after compile-to-runDebug lag, then when the debug program exited, another 1 minute delay to 
get control again of visual studio. I did clean all, but no joy.

Solution: I manually deleted the *.sdf and *.suo files in my project/solution and rebuilt. Issue went away magically.

Not sure why, but something was out of sync, corrupted, or incompatible with the update and needed to be blown away manually.